# Can't boot Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, but it doesn't boot. The system gets stuck here.

[image]

This is second time I've had this issue. The first time was on another PC. I had to erase everything and install Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: The instructions are right there on your screen. If you do not understand those instructions, or you do not understand what the logs tell you, then back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu. The most common reason for this occurrence is that your release-upgrade was unsuccessful.